# I'm in trouble with Intermec PF8t Label Printer

Tags: drivers, printing

I have a Intermec PF8t Desktop Label Printer that works with an Edimax Print Server.. The printer doesn't have any Linux or Ubuntu Driver.. I tried both 14.04 and 16.04 editions.. I read lots of thing on internet about it.. But I couldn't have any solution.. I can't print anything with it..

I allways have "client-error-document-format-not-supported" error any help wil be very valuable...

Thanks..

Comment: http://intermec.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/13994/~/how-to-print-to-an-intermec-printer-from-unix-%2F-linux%3F

Comment: un fortunately I read and try to that million times.. No help!